# Are go-arounds prohibited at St Barth (TFFJ)?

Tags: approach, go-around

The description of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-kKADW-UIs) claims that past a certain point — which is around the turn to final — on approach to TFFJ (St. Barth) runway 28, a go-around is prohibited. That sounds strange. I understand how going around might be impossible past a certain point at VNLK (Lukla) or LFLJ (Courchevel), because the hill ahead is too steep to outclimb and too close to turn away from. But while there is a small hill beyond this runway too, it should be low enough to outclimb to much further. So:

- Is a go-around prohibited past a certain point on approach to TFFJ runway 28?
- If yes, it is prohibited from as early as the video suggests (around final turn, still well above the hill beyond the runway)?
- And if yes, what are the reasons for it?

Comment: Is there an approach chart or at least an airfield plate?

Comment: @CptReynolds, the airport even has scheduled service, so there should be, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video's description reads:

> After passing Eden Rock (min 02:39) it is prohibited to conduct a Go Around.

Below is at 2:39:

[image]

The [official eAIP](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/dvd/eAIP_23_MAY_2019/CAR-SAM-NAM/AIRAC-2019-05-23/html/eAIP/FR-AD-2.TFFJ-fr-FR.html#AD-2.eAIP.TFFJ) reads (link may die):

> **AD 2 TFFJ.AD 2.22 Flight procedures**
>
> 22.2 Arrival flights:
>   RWY 28:
>
> Going around is prohibited in short final.

If Eden Rock is that tiny island on the left, then it makes sense as the plane would be aligned and on short final after passing it, where a right break option is no longer available.

So the answer to the first two questions is yes.

The reasons are not on the chart, so possibly the clearance gradient was not met, was not demonstrated, or the risk to the road and community past the tiny hill is too high.

Also note AD 2 TFFJ.AD 2.21:

> Take-offs on RWY 28 prohibited.

[image]
([eAIP chart](https://www.sia.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/dvd/eAIP_23_MAY_2019/CAR-SAM-NAM/AIRAC-2019-05-23/html/eAIP/Cartes/TFFJ/AD%202%20TFFJ%20ATT%2001.pdf))

Comment: If it was gradient and turbulence based, you'd think there would also be a prohibition of departures from Rwy 28 no?

Comment: @JohnK: 28 dep is prohibited if you check the linked AIP.

Comment: The saddle in the terrain at the departure end would create vicious venturi effect winds, on top of all the rotor, so it's easy to see why. So if you fly there, whether or not the forecast winds will let you depart is the number one limitation.

Answer (score 1):

He’s talking about the VFR pattern for Rwy 28.  Yes some airports, due to terrain or other obstacles do have points where by normal procedures, are one way in past certain points in the approach.  If you do a lot of mountain flying, you’ll find that’s the case with a lot of remote airstrips.  Courchevel in the French Alps is another airport with a one-way-in-only final approach.  Gustaf III is considered one of the most difficult and demanding airports to land at and I know requires special training for approval to land there.  It does however allow for a Go-Around up until passing Eden Rock, so you better be stabilized and on airspeed prior to that.  Once past that, you are committed to landing.

Comment: you are committed to landing.... or crashing